# Is there a way to run only selected tests in Scalatest and Playspec

Tags: scalatest

My test class has several tests.

```
class UserControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec {
"some A" should {
 "do stuff" in {
...
}

"some B" should {
 "do stuff" in {
...
}

"some C" should {
 "do stuff" in {
...
}
```

I can run all the specs or only 1 spec. Is there a way by which I can run say only the 1st and the 3rd spec? In `jasmine` for example, I can mark a test case with `x` to exclude it from running. Is there a similar option in `Scalatest` and `Playspec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ScalaTest [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#selectingSuitesAndTests):

> `-t` argument allows a test to be selected by its (complete) test
>   name.

For example, to run the first and third tests in your suite, enter sbt shell, and then write

```
testOnly UserControllerUnitSpec -- -t "some A should do stuff" -t "some C should do stuff"
```